# Highstocks chart multiple pane width and y axis alignment issue

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have issue with the width and alignment of y axis for each pane in my highstock multiple pane chart.

This issue is observed only if there are more than 2 panes in the highstocks chart.

What is the issue here?

```
$(function() {

var groupingUnits = [
        [
            'minute', // unit name
            [60] // allowed multiples
        ],
        [
            'day', [1]],
        [
            'week', [1]],
        [
            'month', [1]]
    ];
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

his_WscaleTranstek_chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                },

                marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    symbol: 'cirlce',
                    states: {
                        select: {
                            fillColor: 'red',
                            lineWidth: 0,
                            radius: 5
                        }
                    }
                },

                cursor: 'pointer',

            }

        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 2,
            buttons: [{
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 60,
                    text: '1h'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1d'
                }, {
                    type: 'week',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1w'
                }, {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1m'
                }, {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 3,
                    text: '3m'
                }, {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 6,
                    text: '6m'
                }, {
                    type: 'year',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1y'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }]
        },
        yAxis: [
            {
                opposite: false,
                min: 0,
                max: 50,
                tickInterval: 5,
                top:'0%',
                height: '15%',
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'y Axis 1 '
                },
                plotBands: [{
                        from: 0,
                        to: 16,
                        color: 'rgba(16, 180, 146, 0.56)'
                    }, {
                        from: 16,
                        to: 19,
                        color: 'rgba(0, 195, 206, 0.5)'
                    }, {
                        from: 19,
                        to: 25,
                        color: 'rgba(7, 235, 78, 0.68)'
                    }, {
                        from: 25,
                        to: 30,
                        color: 'rgba(225, 239, 6, 0.68)'
                    }, {
                        from: 30,
                        to: 40,
                        color: 'rgba(239, 134, 5, 0.5)'
                    }, {
                        from: 40,
                        to: 50,
                        color: 'rgba(251, 44, 6, 0.5)'
                    }
                ],
                lineWidth: 2,
                //maxPadding: 0,
                endOnTick: false,
                gridLineWidth: 0
            }, {
                opposite: false,
                min: 20,
                max: 280,
                tickInterval: 10,
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'y Axis 2'
                },

                lineWidth: 1,
                top: '17%',
                height: '15%',
                offset: 0,
                //maxPadding: 0,
                endOnTick: false,
                gridLineWidth: 0
            },{
                opposite: false,
                min: 0,
                max: 50,
                tickInterval: 5,
                top: '34%',
                height: '15%',
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'y Axis 3'
                },

                lineWidth: 2,
                //maxPadding: 0,
                endOnTick: false,
                gridLineWidth: 0
            },
            {
                opposite: false,
                min: 0,
                max: 80,
                tickInterval: 5,
                top: '51%',
                height: '15%',
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'y Axis 4'
                },
                plotBands: [],
                lineWidth: 2,
                maxPadding: 0,
                endOnTick: false,
                gridLineWidth: 0
            },
            {
                opposite: false,
                min: 10,
                max: 70,
                tickInterval: 5,
                top: '68%',
                height: '15%',
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'y Axis 5'
                },
                plotBands: [],
                lineWidth: 2,
                maxPadding: 0,
                endOnTick: false,
                gridLineWidth: 0
            },{
                opposite: false,
                min: 0,
                max: 8,
                tickInterval: 5,
                top: '85%',
                height: '15%',
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'y Axis 6'
                },
                plotBands: [],
                lineWidth: 2,
                maxPadding: 0,
                endOnTick: false,
                gridLineWidth: 0
            }
        ],
        title: {
            text: 'Chart',
            style: {
                color: '#4e80b2'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
            itemStyle: {
                'cursor': 'default'
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'BMI',
                data: [15,15,15,15,15,15,15],
                lineColor: "#777d7d",
                "tooltip": {
                    pointFormatter: function () {
                        var point = this;
                        return '<span style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + point.series.name + ': <b>' + Math.round((point.y)) + ' </b><br/>';
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    fillColor: 'white',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: "#777d7d"
                },
                yAxis: 0,
                showInLegend: false
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'WEIGHT',
                data:  [15,15,15,15,15,15,15],
                lineColor: "#777d7d",
                "tooltip": {
                    pointFormatter: function () {
                        var point = this;
                        return '<span style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + point.series.name + ': <b>' + (point.y) + ' kg</b><br/>';
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    fillColor: 'white',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: "#777d7d"
                },
                yAxis: 1,
                showInLegend: false
            },

            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Fat %',
                data:  [15,15,15,15,15,15,15],
                lineColor: "#777d7d",
                "tooltip": {
                    pointFormatter: function () {
                        var point = this;
                        return '<span style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + point.series.name + ': <b>' + (point.y) + ' kg</b><br/>';
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    fillColor: 'white',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: "#777d7d"
                },
                yAxis: 2,
                showInLegend: false
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Water %',
                data: [15,15,15,15,15,15,15],
                lineColor: "#777d7d",
                "tooltip": {
                    pointFormatter: function () {
                        var point = this;
                        return '<span style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + point.series.name + ': <b>' + (point.y) + ' kg</b><br/>';
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    fillColor: 'white',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: "#777d7d"
                },
                yAxis: 3,
                showInLegend: false
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Muscle mass',
                data:  [15,15,15,15,15,15,15],
                lineColor: "#777d7d",
                "tooltip": {
                    pointFormatter: function () {
                        var point = this;
                        return '<span style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + point.series.name + ': <b>' + (point.y) + ' kg</b><br/>';
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    fillColor: 'white',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: "#777d7d"
                },
                yAxis: 4,
                showInLegend: false
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Bone Weight',
                data:  [15,15,15,15,15,15,15],
                lineColor: "#777d7d",
                "tooltip": {
                    pointFormatter: function () {
                        var point = this;
                        return '<span style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + point.series.name + ': <b>' + (point.y) + ' kg</b><br/>';
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    fillColor: 'white',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: "#777d7d"
                },
                yAxis: 5,
                showInLegend: false
            }
        ],
        navigator: {
            height: 30
        }
    }
)

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devnigel/churfL0p/20/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set [yAxis.offset](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.offset) for the axes.

```
 yAxis: [{
  offset: 0,
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/gahjh1uz/